# Batch Loop in file.txt to chunk large folder

Tags: batch-file

I want to chunk a huge folder containing more than 200 000 files in subfolders

Structure of my source (simplified for the example) :

```
Source Folder
   |_ Sub1
       |_ Sub1_file1.txt
       |_ Sub1_file2.txt
   |_ Sub2
       |_Sub2_file1.txt
       |_ ...
       |_Sub2_file11111.txt
```

**So every name of every file is unique.**

So i create txt file with :

```
dir %Source% /s /b /a-d > %Target%\input.txt
```

And now I want to create a new subfolder every 10 000 files, so :

```
 Set NameSubF = 0
 Set MaxLimit = 1000
 FOR /F "tokens=* delims=" %%a IN (input.txt) DO (
    if %%a==!MaxLimit
```

**** Here I am lost but i want to create a new subfolder ****

```
    COPY "%%a" "%destfolder%\%%~nxa"
```

Comment: I think it may be wise to provide an example of your starting tree structure and your wanted destination structure,_preferably with real file and directory names_.

Comment: The real file and directory names doesn't matter in this case, right ?

Comment: The problem is that when just a minimal code snippet is supplied and other items aren't we have to try and guess things and often have to provide less efficient or more basic code. This is in order for the OP, or person of unknown ability, to try to modify it in such a way as they can plug it into their existing un-supplied code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this should work (don't forget to adjust destfolder):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL EnableDelayedExpansion
SET destfolder=I:\SomeFolder\Folder
SET MaxLimit=1000
FOR /F "tokens=1,2,3 delims=:" %%A IN ('findstr /r /n "^" input.txt') DO (
    SET /a prefix=%%A/%MaxLimit%
    SET dest=%destfolder%!prefix!
    IF NOT EXIST !dest! mkdir !dest!
    COPY I:\list.txt "!dest!\%%~nxC"
)
```

This code requires your files to have different names. If there is a file like `C:\A\file.txt` and there is also a file `C:\B\sdklfj\XYZ\file.txt` they might be copied into the same destination folder. In this case the `C:\A\file.txt` will be overwritten.

One last point: when coding in batch, do not put spaces where they are not really required! Here is why (_ means space):

```
SET a=hello    ::%a% is hello
SET b =hello   ::%b% doesn't exist but %b_% does and it is equal to %a%
SET c= hello   ::%c% is _hello so %a% != %c%
SET d = hello  ::%d% doesn't exist but %d_% does and it is equal to %c% but not to %b_% or %a%
```

Or this:

```
@ECHO OFF
SET a=hello
SET a =123
ECHO %a%
ECHO %a %
```

will output this:

```
hello
123
```

When working with numbers batch will autocorrect some of these issues but when working with strings, it's a real mess! To avoid this just write `set x=y` instead of `set x = y` or `set "x=y"`.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Can you explain "SET /a prefix=%%A/%MaxLimit%" ?

Comment: @DanielE. `%%A` is the line number. So we are dividing the line number by 1000 or 10000 or which number of files you want to be in each directory. As batch doesn't support decimals, the outcome will be floored to the next multiple of 1000 (e.g. 4711/1000=4). This is how you calculate the prefix.

Comment: It returns always the lower int ?